# RxJava: How to modify only first item before sending it to observer

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have a Rx stream which sends multiple items to the observer. 
But I would like to modify the very first item that is sent back. All the other items can be sent, as is.

I know `map()` would intercept all the items, but I would then have to keep a counter of which item is currently being emitted. 
Is there a way to do this only for the very first item?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Say you have a stream of strings `["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]`  and you need to modify the very first item only

```
Observable<String> stringObservable = Observable.just("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth").publish().refCount();
stringObservable.skip(1)
            .startWith(stringObservable.take(1).map(s -> "Modified"))
            .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(String s) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
            });
```

the result will be

```
    Modified
    Second
    Third
    Fourth
```

Comment: It's important to note that introducing two subscriptions may introduce side effects. You can use `publish()` to subscribe only once, effectively. `stringObservable.publish( shared -> shared.skip(1).startsWith(shared.take(1).map(...))...`

Comment: Yes. noted it. Since publish() will multicast and turn the source into a `Connectableobservable`, added `publish().refCount()` combination to turn it into a multicasted Observable, which is shared for every subscriber added. Updated the answer

Comment: This doesn't work if upstream is a hot observable since the part with `skip(1)` won't be subscribed to until _after_ the `startWith` stream. You will miss the second emission.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Sarath Kn's answer, here is a more robust version that handles the case where upstream is a hot observable.

```java
    upstream.publish(stream ->
        Observable.concatEager(
            List.of(
                stream.take(1).map(s -> "Modified"),
                stream.skip(1))
        )
    )
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This way `upstream` can be hot. E.g.,:

```java
    Observable.create(emitter -> {
        List<String> values = List.of("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth");
        for (String value : values) {
            if (emitter.isDisposed())
                break;
            emitter.onNext(value);
        }
    })
    .publish(...as above...)
```